# What is the maximum value EpGap can take?

Tags: java, optimization, cplex

I am using CPLEX Java library in my optimization code. In CPLEX library, user can change the default value of gap value by calling setParam(DoubleParam.EpGap, 0.01) etc. What is the max value that a user can set with setParam() in case of EpGap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPGAP is a fraction, so you can set it to **any value between 0.0 and 1.0.** (If the acceptable gap is large, the MIP will terminate sooner.)

You can find some [documentation here](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/teaching/xct/cplex/refparameterscplex.pdf).

From the CPLEX 10.0 PARAMETER Reference manual

```
CPX_PARAM_EPGAP 
EpGap Any number from 0.0 to 1.0
mip tolerances mipgap Default: 1e -04
Code: 2009 
Type double
```

Comment: Thanks. That document is useful. I have seen another parameter "EpAGap" on ibm's reference website and it was saying "Any nonnegative number" for that parameter. What is the difference between EpAGap and EpGap?

Comment: The difference between EPAGAP and EPGAP is that the 'A' stands for absolute. EPGAP is the *relative* gap. So if you have a numeric gap value that you can accept, you'd use EPAGAP. [See here for the difference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FCPLEX%2FUser_manual%2Ftopics%2Fuss_solveMIP_46.html)